# How to save a non serializable model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've created a model with custom layers, which have matrix operations and stuff like that. I want to now, after training, save my model. I've tried:

```
model.save("model.h5", save_format='tf')
```

But an error comes out:

```
NotImplementedError: Saving the model to HDF5 format requires the model to be 
a Functional model or a Sequential model. It does not work for subclassed models, 
because such models are defined via the body of a Python method, which isn't safely serializable.
Consider saving to the Tensorflow SavedModel format (by setting save_format="tf") or using `save_weights`.
```

I've found something that works:

```
checkpoint_path = "checkpoints"

ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(model=model,
                           optimizer=optimizer)

ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=5)

# if a checkpoint exists, restore the latest checkpoint.
if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
  ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
```

My question is: by using this way, I could do the same as saving a serializable model (like a Sequential Model), or this checkpoints is used for other purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two formats you can use to save your model. Either you simply save your model with the older Keras H5 format `model.save("test", save_format='h5')` or you use the `Tensorflow SavedModel format` by either explicitly setting `model.save("test", save_format='tf')` or simply `model.save("test")`, since the `tf` format is used by default when you call `model.save`. With `model.save("model.h5", save_format='tf')`, you seem to be trying to use both formats at once, which does not look like it is working. Saving your model with the `tf` format should work. More information can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize). The following model, for example, can only be saved when using `model.save` or `model.save("test", save_format='tf')`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class SomeModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super(SomeModel, self).__init__()
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu, )
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = SomeModel()
model.compute_output_shape(input_shape=(1,1))
model.save("model")
```

Calling `model.save("test", save_format='h5')` or `model.save("test.h5")` or even `model.save("model.h5", save_format='tf')` on this subclassed model will in result in an error.

`Checkpoints` are especially useful when you need to interrupt the training or it crashes and you want to resume training your model from a saved state. During inference, you could easily load the latest checkpoint of your model and make predictions without having to recompile it.